# Узнать, куда указывает символьная ссылка

Tags: c++, delphi, windows, winapi, c++builder

Есть junction типа такого:

```
mklink /d /j some-link some-folder-that-never-existed
```

Насколько я понимаю, в линуксе чтобы по такой ссылке получить путь предназначена функция [`readlink`](//linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) из `<unistd.h>`, а nodejs - функция [`fs.readlink`](//nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readlink_path_options_callback) (в windows она работает).

А какие функции следует использовать, чтобы на Си++ получить ту же функциональность?

[Использовать](//stackoverflow.com/q/23409775/4928642) `CreateFile` для получения хэндла, а затем `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` для получения имени файла не подходит, т. к. целевой файл не существует. А при использовании флага `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` получается путь к самой ссылке, а не к целевой папке.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59787/discussion-on-question-by-qwertiy-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартным путем для получения имени целевого файла/директории символических ссылок в Delphi используется метод `TFile.getSymLinkTarget()` из `System.IOUtils`. Однако, если ссылка некорректная (целевой файл отсутствует) то вызов сей функции вызывает исключение.

Использовать `CreateFile` и `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` для получения желаемого результата тоже не удалось.

*В качестве тестового примера я создал файл `d:\data.txt`, создал на него ссылку `mklink sl.txt data.txt`, затем переименовал файл `data.txt`. Таким образом ссылка становится некорректной.*

В качества альтернативного варианта для получения нужной информации можно воспользоваться функцией [`deviceIoControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx), позволяющей отправлять команды непосредственно устройствам, среди которых может быть файловая система. Среди [управляющих команд работы с директориями](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363948(v=vs.85).aspx) есть код [`FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364571(v=vs.85).aspx) для получения сведений о ссылках и точках монтирования. В качестве результата вызова этой команды возвращается структура [`REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552012.aspx) в которой не совсем логичным образом представлены необходимые данные.

К сожалению мои навыки работы с delphi несколько утратились за последнее время когда я с ним не работал, так что код может быть  несколько корявым. Структуру переписал следующим образом (она вроде есть в JVCL):

```
type
  REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER = packed record
      ReparseTag: Cardinal;
      ReparseDataLength: Word;
      Reserved: Word;
      SubstituteNameOffset: Word;
      SubstituteNameLength: Word;
      PrintNameOffset: Word;
      PrintNameLength: Word;
      Flags: Cardinal;
      PathBuffer: array[0..1000] of WideChar;
  end;

  TReparseDataBuffer = REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER;
  PReparseDataBuffer = ^TReparseDataBuffer;
```

*Не особо мне понятно, какого размера буфер для выходных данных необходимо передавать, но выделить место под него должен вызывающий код. В противном случае будет получена ошибка, что недостаточный размер структуры.*

```
const SL_NAME = 'D:\sl.txt';
var
  h : THandle;
  path : string;
  rdb : TReparseDataBuffer;
  br : cardinal;
  res : Longbool;
begin
    ZeroMemory(@rdb, sizeof(rdb));;

    h := CreateFile(SL_NAME,
            FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
            FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT + FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            0);

     res := DeviceIoControl(h, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, nil, 0, @rdb, sizeof(rdb), br, nil);

     SetString(path,  pchar(@rdb.PathBuffer[rdb.PrintNameOffset div sizeof(WideChar)]),
                      rdb.PrintNameLength div sizeof(WideChar));

     writeln('target:', path);
     CloseHandle(h);

     readln;
end.
```

При открытии файла добавляется флаг `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT`, возвращающий дескриптор ссылки, а не файла назначения. Для ссылок на каталоги необходим `FILE_FLAT_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` (честно подсмотрено в кодe `TFile.getSymlinkTarget()`).

В структуре `TReparseDataBuffer` указывается смещение и длина начала имени файла назначения в буфере в байтах.

Comment: OPEN_ALWAYS - If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set to zero. Т. е. если она сможет, то создаст новый файл, а если не сможет, то всё равно ошибка? Что-то не то...

Comment: @Qwertiy блин я лох. Он действительно создал новый файл `data.txt` :D

Comment: Спасибо! И на будущее, при правке или восстановлении ответа автору вопроса уведомление не приходит.

Comment: @Qwertiy про уведомления буду знать :) странно, вообще, конечно. Про правку то понятно, но про восстановление, странно.